# Pinescript Asynchronous function calls /callbacks

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

does pinescript have async function calls or callbacks?

Use case is run a complex calculation in function 1 one hundred times. When totally done, run function 2.

For example, filter 100 tickers whose Ema is above the 200 Ema. Then populate a table with results.  I would need to dynamically know the number of rows of the table first before populating.

Comment: Short answer - no

Comment: Don't think of Pine as a real programming language. However I see no benefit of an async solution to the problem you stated. Why not run `function 1` 100 times, then run `function 2` with the result of `function 1`?